# Access java control panel when Control panel is blocked

Tags: java, control-panel

I'm using computer in library to open Java program, but unfortunately, the error 'Applications blocked by security settings' appear. I need to lower the security settings. I can't access the Java control panel because the control panel and drive C is blocked. Is there any way to lower java security settings without going to control panel?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, open the Run Box(*press* [image] + <kbd>R</kbd>) and type `%SystemRoot%\system32\javacpl.cpl` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: The run box is blocked.

Comment: @user74158 then it looks like you can't do it if you can't access the control panel, the run box, cmd.exe or the c:\ drive. Have you asked the library staff for help?